# MySQL query becomes slow

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by

I am having the following query that is supposed to give almost 50 rows as output. It is searching from table having less than 10K records. It takes almost 5 minutes to run the query

```
select a.dak_dept,b.dept_name,
  (
    select count(dak_stat) 
      from dak_dept_mast 
        where dak_dept = a.dak_dept and dak_stat='N'
  ) as new,
  (
    select count(dak_stat)
      from dak_dept_mast 
        where dak_dept = a.dak_dept and dak_stat='O'
  ) as open,
  (
    select count(dak_stat)
      from dak_dept_mast
        where dak_dept = a.dak_dept and dak_stat='C'
  ) as closed
  from dak_dept_mast a,tapal_dept_mast b
  where a.dak_dept = b.dept_code
  group by a.dak_dept
```

The table dak_dept_mast has dak_dept and dak_no as a combination primary key
The table tapal_dept_mast has dept_code as primary key.

Can somebody suggest something. I  am running mysql 5.1 using XAMPP

Thx in advance

Sujeesh

Comment: Have you looked at the `explain` output?

Comment: @ChrisHeald I did not get you Chris. Sorry I am new to this.

Comment: MySQL has a [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain-output.html) syntax which will show you the query plan for a given query. You can use it to help figure out why a query is slow. Unrelated, though, last I looked subselects were extremely suboptimal in MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try an alternative

```
SELECT a.dak_dept,
       b.dept_name,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.dak_stat='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) new,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.dak_stat='O' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) open,
       SUM(CASE WHEN a.dak_stat='C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) closed
  FROM dak_dept_mast a JOIN tapal_dept_mast b
    ON a.dak_dept = b.dept_code
 GROUP BY a.dak_dept
```

Comment: Man, That worked like Charm....By the way can you please explain what took the oar??

Comment: Dependent subqueries are very slow in MySQL. Most of the time you can use JOINs instead and it works much faster.

Comment: @user2652532 Sorry for being late with an answer for your followup question. Correlated subqueries are evaluated for each row of an outer select and you had three of them. That slows things down. The proposed query do it all in one go using conditional count.